# Determine the x,y,z coordinates of any point on a line defined by two 3D points using distance from origin-point as the third parameter?

Tags: c#, geometry

If we have two points in 3D space, does C# have any high-level libraries that would return the x,y,z coordinates of a point that is a specified distance along the line defined by the two points, using one of the points as origin?

```
     extrapolatedPoint = FindPoint( origin3dPoint, second3dPoint, distanceFromOrigin)
```

P.S. The line defined by the points isn't a line-segment with the two points as endpoints, but a line that passes through the points.

P.P.S. Adding an image to show the practical purpose. I'm trying to write an app that would calculate lumber lengths as well as the compound cut angles for a splay-leg "trapezoidal" tool stand. The user must specify a) the height of the stand b) the dimensions of the stand's rectangular footprint c) the dimensions of the stand's smaller table surface and d) the nominal size of the lumber being used (e.g. two by four). I need to extrapolate the 3D point at a location 3/4 of the length in order to calculate the lengths of the cross-braces there.

[image: splay leg tool stand]

Comment: You are calculating a line formula that is : z = ax + by + c.  And you have a formula distance = sqrt( x^2 + y^2 + z^2).  You are given 7 inputs :  3 inputs are point A.  3 inputs are point B.  And a distance d.  From the 2 points you first get the line formula solving for a, b, and c.  You then find the point on the line that gives distance.

Comment: @jdweng Your formula is for plane, not for line.

Comment: @MBo : How can it be a plane when for each x, y combination there is only one Z.

Comment: Yes, exactly, `for each x, y combination there is only one Z. ` defines a plane.  Two non-parallel planes define a line as their intersection.  There is no such simple equation for line in 3D [example link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404440/what-is-the-equation-for-a-3d-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate unit direction vector (perhaps there are ready-to-use functions in C# math library - I see `Vector.Normalize` if it's suitable)

```
dx = P2.x - P1.x
dy = P2.y - P1.y
dz = P2.z - P1.z
Len = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz)
dx /= Len 
dy /= Len 
dz /= Len
```

Now you can define point at line with distance `D` from the first point (in direction of `P2`!) as

```
x  = P1.x + D * dx
y  = P1.y + D * dy
z  = P1.z + D * dz
```

Note that there are two points with distance `D` from the origin on the line, so I emphasized  direction.

**Edit:**
In comments author wants to her point at 3/4 (or another value) of P1-P2 way. In this case length is not needed, just make linear interpolation

```
 t = 3.0/4
 x = P1.x * (1 - t) + P2.x * t
 y = P1.y * (1 - t) + P2.y * t
 z = P1.z * (1 - t) + P2.z * t
```

or use C# ready-to-use function [System.Numerics.Vector3.Lerp](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3.lerp?view=net-6.0)

```
extrapolatedPoint = Lerp(P1, P2, 0.75)
```

Comment: You are wrong.  There can be zero points and one point as well as two points.  The solution is where a line intersects a sphere.  The line may never intersect with a sphere and a line may be tangent to the sphere and intersect at one point.

Comment: @jdweng Perhaps we have distinct interpretations of the task. I mean something like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/LinearInterpolation.svg/800px-LinearInterpolation.svg.png)

Comment: You are assuming the line goes through the sphere in two locations.  I'm saying the line may not go through the sphere or may be tangent to the sphere.

Comment: Sorry, but -  what sphere are you talking about? Author writes about line through two points, and the third point lies on the same line like my picture shows, but in 3D

Comment: The distance from origin point is a sphere.

Comment: @jdweng Title says: coordinates of any point **on a line**

Comment: @Tim Things are much simpler for 3/4 of the length    `x= (P1.x + 3*P2.x)/4` and so on

Comment: @MBo. Yes, but how do I calculate the length of the cross braces without knowing the 3D point 3/4 along the leg?  My CalcLength function is `var length=  (Double) Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(PP.P2.x - PP.P1.x, 2.00) + Math.Pow(PP.P2.y - PP.P1.y, 2.00) + Math.Pow(PP.P2.z - PP.P1.z, 2.00))`.   I am probably missing something obvious to anyone who does this regularly but I haven't been working with angles and coordinates for many a year.

Comment: The direction vector gives me that point along the leg, right? `x  = P1.x + D * dx etc etc` and  `D` would be `3/4 * leg length`?

Comment: Yes, D = 3/4 * leg length. But as I wrote, you really don't need leg length with `x= (P1.x + 3*P2.x)/4` expressions. Moreover, in c# `P3=Vector3.Lerp(P1, P2, 0.75)` [does the job](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3.lerp?view=net-6.0)

Comment: The origin is point (0,0,0).  Nothing says the line goes through the origin.  You are looking for a point on a line that is a distance from the origin.  The line may be further away from the origin that the distance.  The line may be a tangent and have only one intersect.

Comment: @jdweng The first paragraph:   `using one of the points as origin`

Comment: @Tim Is my answer still unclear?

Comment: @MBo:   I need to read up on Linear Interpolation. Thank your for the help!